# Using textfield result as name for function

Tags: python, maya

I want to use a textfield entry to serve as naming a new created blenshape. 
The error reads : " Invalid deformer name was specified "

Here is what I have so far, which doesn't work unfortunately:

```
def blendButton (self, *args):
    #create BlendShape button
        cmds.separator(h=15)
        self.widgets["textfield"]= cmds.textField(fi="Your BS name")
        cmds.button(label="Create BlendShape ", w=295, h=30, al="center",  c=self.blendShape) 

def blendShape (self, *args): 
        cmds.blendShape ( cmds.ls(sl=True)[1], cmds.ls(sl=True)[0],  frontOfChain=True, n= self.widgets["textfield"])
```

self.widgets["textfield"] seems not to be a valid Argument.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you want to query the value textfield widget:

```
 blendshape_name = cmds.textField(self.widgets['textfield'], q=True, text=True)
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer !
This works but it only takes the already set letters when I open the script. Once I enter new text it won't update it as my blendshape Name.
Do you know how I can make it check if new text has been added to the TextBox ?

Comment: you can make the function update using the `changeCommand` flag on the textField. However you will only get events when the user hits tab or enter -- not on every keystroke. Default maya doesn't do that.